# Entity Framework Core compare two child collection properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core and stuck in a scenario where I need to fetch all the Parent table records that has child records matching the given child records.
Example:

Parent Table

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P1 |
| 2 | P2 |
| 3 | P3 |

Child Table

| Id | ParentId | Name | Age | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | C1 | 20 | abc |
| 2 | 1 | C2 | 25 | xyz |
| 3 | 2 | C1 | 20 | qqq |
| 4 | 2 | C2 | 25 | wer |
| 5 | 3 | C3 | 30 | tyu |

I need Linq to get all parents which matches below search parameters.

All prents with Child records same as:
Child: [ {C1,20}, {C2,25}]

So, it should return the Parent P1 and P2 as result.
I am trying EqualityComparer but getting not translated error from EF.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Propably something like that should work
`.Parent.Where(_ => _.Childs.Any(item => item.C1 == 20)`

Comment: I need to match all the child record with a list of child records. Both list should match for specific properties.

Comment: Depends how you want to do it. you can load using EF, like `include`, etc. Or you can do plain LINQ (not extension) so you can generate an anonymous type which will fit your need. Sometimes this is only way you can do it to achieve certain results. I feel, this is the case when you can't get away with just linq extension method.

Comment: [check this out from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think EF supports this. I didn't find a direct solution when I was in the same situation (multi-column primary key on the child table). My workaround was to add artificial (computed+stored) string column to the child table that combined all the PK parts, after that you should be able to do:

```cs
var childrenKeys = new List<string>();
/* .... fill it with children keys you are interested in ... */
var parents = dbContext.Parents
    .Where(x => x.Children.Any(xx => childrenKeys.Contains(xx.NameAndAge))
    .ToList();
```

Only other option I know of is to switch to client side evaluation and filter it yourself.

Comment: This answer is most suitable in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I've changed my answer as your comment provided me information I didn't have. I believe you might be searching for this:

```
var childrenConditions = new List<Child>()
{
    new Child() 
    {
        Name = "C1",
        Age = 20
    },
    new Child() 
    {
        Name = "C2",
        Age = 25
    },
}

var children = context.Children.Include(child => child.Parent);
var groupedChildren = children.GroupBy(child => child.Parent.Id);
var rightParents = new List<Parent>();

foreach(var group in groupedChildren)
{
    var respectsConditions = true;
    foreach(var condition in childrenConditions)
    {
        if ((group.Select(child => 
            child.Name != condition.Name ||
            child.Age != condition.Age)).Any())
        {
            respectsConditions = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (respectsCondition) 
    {
        rightParents.Add(group.First().Parent);
    }
}
```

At the end of the algorithm, 'rightParents' will be a collection containing the parents you're searching for.

Comment: I'd use `.Children.Any(...)` instead of `.Count == 2`. Otherwise good answer if the number of children we want to find is known at compile time - I assumed that is not the case (name and age values can be variable).

Comment: Hi @huancz. I believe 'Any' wouldn't work, because we need to have exactly 2 matches, not 1+. Regarding the hardcoded 2, I am expecting Dev S not to implement the literal '2', but instead make a count on the number of conditions he needs to match.

Comment: Ok, you have a point here, it's not clearly specified if any child will satisfy the filter, or all must be present (btw `== 2` will fall apart if you allow duplicate children). Main thing I was trying to say is that in in one call you may want to search for parents who have "these-two-children-by-name-and-age". In next call you might want "parents with three children". The `.Count` itself may be variable. So, expression inside the `.Where` will be different each time too. You can't do that without building the ExpressionTree dynamically.

Comment: The number of child a parent can have is not fixed. So it is a list that needs to be compared.

Comment: Ok @DevS, check my new answer.